# C# referencing static field with like-named local variable

Tags: c#, scope

In a rather limiting context I need to reference a static class field from a constructor that has a variable named with the same name as the static field. Here is an example to illustrate, which also includes a non-static field to highlight the fact that for non-static fields one can use "this" to reference the class-field:

```
public class Example () {

    private static DateTime firstInstance;
    private static DateTime referenceInstance;

    private String Name;

    static Example() {
        first=DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Example(String Name, DateTime referenceInstance) {
        this.Name=Name;
        referenceInstance=referenceInstance;
    }
}
```

How can one access the "referenceInstance" static field without the "this" keyword as one does with "Name"? In a perfect world I would just refactor either the class variable or the constrictor variable to have a different identifier, however for a rather technical reason (printing documentation) neither can be changed here.

Thanks.

Comment: "private static final DateTime firstInstance;"? Is this C# or Java?

Comment: @Dima: Sorry, that was just an example that I pulled out of thin air to illustrate. I didn't even notice that I added the Java keyword. Sorry, removed now. Nice catch!

Comment: Yes the c# equivalent would be `private static readonly DateTime firstInstance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully qualify the static variable name in the constructor.

```
public Example(String Name, DateTime referenceInstance) {
 this.Name=Name;
 Example.referenceInstance=referenceInstance;
}
```